# flash disk not recognized after shortcut virus deleted

Tags: flash, data-recovery, shortcuts

my flash disk infected by a windows computer. later I inserted flash disk on ubuntu; all my folders were under an unnamed folder and there were *.lnk and some unknown files. I copied my folders to the main directory and deleted unnamed directory and *.lnk and other unknown files. now flash disk is not recognized by ubuntu. I checked with gparted, the partition is there; but I do not want to format because I need to rescue the folders.
what can I do?

Output from: **`sudo fdisk -l`**

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8054112256 bytes, 15730688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2c3c8a4c

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       63 15730687 15730625  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/loop0: 2.8 GiB, 2969686016 bytes, 5800168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/sda: 14.5 GiB, 15597895680 bytes, 30464640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

**sdb** is live Ubuntu; **sda** is the flash disk.

But flash disk not recognized; the files or folders cannot be browsed.

update:
I tried to recover the partition by testdisk. I got the error: Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55

Comment: Can you post the output of "sudo fdisk -l"

Answer (score 1):

Given that your step 2 ('*I copied my folders to the main directory*') may NOT have actually completed properly, you are best advised to treat this as a straight **data recovery** exercise.

Try the vendor tools for data recovery (probably Windows-based), to find/retrieve your 'lost' folders.

---

**NOTE:** *Many possible ways to 'treat' this issue, and gain a viable partition/directory structure, will likely irretrievably lose your data.*

Comment: I tried to recover the partition by testdisk.
I got the error: 
Partition sector doesn't have the endmark 0xAA55

Answer (score 0):

sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sdb: 7.5 GiB, 8054112256 bytes, 15730688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2c3c8a4c

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *       63 15730687 15730625  7.5G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

Disk /dev/loop0: 2.8 GiB, 2969686016 bytes, 5800168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/sda: 14.5 GiB, 15597895680 bytes, 30464640 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

sdb is live ubuntu. sda is the flash disk. but flash disk not recognized, the files or folders cannot be browsed.